# Jquery no ejecuta mi petición POST y sobre escribe la URL

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con Laravel, Jquery y Yajra JqueryDataTable. Cuando quiero crear un registro funciona muy bien abre al modal, el boton manda a Ajax y Laravel inserta en mi base de datos y el registro se inserta en mi DataTable, si quiero repetir el paso cuando quiero guardar otro registro, el script solo sobre escribe la URL sin ejecutar la petición POST.

Mi Botón

```
<a class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;" href="javascript:void(0)" id="createNewLocation" ><i class="material-icons">add_location</i>&nbsp;Nuevo</a>
```

Limpio mi formulario y abro la ventana modal

```
$('#createNewLocation').click(function () {
    $('#saveBtn').val("create");
    $('#id').val('');
    $('#name_location').val('');
    $('#location').val('');
    $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
    $('#modelHeading').html("Crear nueva locaciòn.");
    $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
});
```

Deshabilito el boton de guardar, ejecuto la petición POST con Ajax, muestro una alerta de exito y reinicio el modal

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    /* Deshabilita el boton */
    $(this).replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="saveBtn" disabled="true" value="create"><i class="material-icons">autorenew</i>&nbsp;</button>');
    //$(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({

      data: $('#productForm').serialize(),
      url: "{{ route('locaciones.store') }}",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {

          $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
          $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');

          $('#modal-alert-message-success').modal('show');
          $("#success-message").html('<h3><i class="material-icons">done</i>&nbsp;Locacion guardada.</h3>');

          table.draw();
      },

      error: function (data) {

          $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
          $('#modal-alert-message-error').modal('show');
          $("#error-message").html('<h3><i class="material-icons">error</i>&nbsp;Error</h3>');

          $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
          $('#ajaxModel').modal('hide');
          $('#saveBtn').replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveBtn" value="create"><i class="material-icons">save</i>&nbsp;</button>');
          $('#saveBtn').attr("disabled", false);

      }

  });

});

$('#modal-alert-message-success').on('shown.bs.modal',function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#modal-alert-message-success').modal('hide');
    }, 1500);
});

$('#ajaxModel').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#productForm').trigger("reset")
    $('#saveBtn').replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveBtn" value="create"><i class="material-icons">save</i>&nbsp;</button>');
    $('#saveBtn').attr("disabled", false);
  });
```

Cuando quiero insertar el segundo registro seguido solo sobre escribe la URL con los parámetros del formulario pero sin ejecutar la petición POST, por ejemplo:

http://project.test/locaciones?id=&name_location=CIUDAD+DE+MEXICO&location=CDMX

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta un poco de información para saber exactamente cual es el problema. Pero lo que veo a simple vista es que tenés un problema con el `onClick()` de `#saveBtn`.

Al hacer:

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {
    ...
});
```

Estás haciendo un bind de ese evento en el elemento `#saveBtn` **existente**. Dentro de tu función estás haciendo un `reaplaceWith()`:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="saveBtn" disabled="true" value="create"><i class="material-icons">autorenew</i>&nbsp;</button>');
```

Al reemplazar el botón por otro (por más que tenga el mismo ID), el bind anterior deja de funcionar.

Tenés 2 opciones:

**Opción 1:**
Hacé el bind sobre el body (o algún elemento padre).

```
$('body').on('click', '#saveBtn', function () {
    ...
});
```

**Opción 2:**
No reemplaces el botón. En vez de hacer un `reaplaceWit()` modificá los atributos/propiedades que necesites.

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true).html('<i class="material-icons">autorenew</i>');
```

Comment: Funciono de maravilla, muchas gracias.